# Is private key suppose to include the \n in it?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, private-key, service-accounts

I create a json key file for my GCP service account, since it's in JSON, it comes in this format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "my-project",
  "private_key_id": "abcde",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQCwrTSu4RbY2I1C\nBaLF7coPwrYBjPCz+p+r1toO3fhVbWh+IWFe0H0wDs8gGe1XUSzbE/ZxlKt5k2jz\n3qoIbPjK/UqM3JlEpwlwDmIzEQuArLMsiZ9hjIEkDn3WbUnYf8SZu4tSFNLLyYcb\nnl...",
   ...
}
```

I am trying to insert it into a 3rd party software that uses it, but it keep giving me key error.  I am wondering if it's because the \n inside the private key is json format artifact and should be removed?

Also should I remove the `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` part?  Is that also json format artifact?

Comment: **giving me key error** is not a good problem description. The **\n** is within the JSON key value, so it does not affect the JSON. Do not remove the **BEGIN PRIVATE KEY** as that string is part of the key format (PKCS-8) which is a PEM Base64 encoded binary value. Edit your question with the problem you have importing the key. Most likely the software is expecting a different format. Look up which format they require.

Comment: The format **"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n[PRIVATE-KEY]\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"** is part of the JSON Key format, and you shouldn't remove it from your Key. Please share more information about the 3rd party software that you are using and details about the key error that you state in your post.

Comment: I am also getting errors regarding the \n on a Linux machine. Did you find out the solution?